# PHP ucwords works on all but first word

Tags: php

I am trying to convert lowercase filenames with underscores into 'proper' 
words with spaces replacing the underscores and uppercase first letter of 
each word to display on webpage.

example filename:
test_one_two_three_four_five.php

What I have that 'should' work: (IMHO)

```
<?php $path = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; 
$path = str_replace('_', ' ', ($path)); 
$path = ucwords($path);
?>

<? echo basename ($path,".php"); ?>
```

The output is "test One Two Three Four Five" which as you can see is not 100% correct.

Where have I gone awry please and how can I get the desired result?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Floyd

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://3v4l.org/OjTGu

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either. Your script prints `Test One Two Three Four Five`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

It works fine if I 'declare' the filename as in: 
$path = 'test_one_two_three_four_five.php';
but with the real filename of "test_one_two_three_four_five.php" and the code given above it will not capitalize the first letter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually when you print the `$path = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`, you will find that at the first place there is "/". first remove this by `str_replace` then do further code.

```
$path = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; 
$path = str_replace('_', ' ', ($path));
$path = str_replace('/', '', ($path)); 
$path = ucwords($path);

echo basename ($path,".php");
```

Comment: DING DING DING!

Works perfectly!

Where does the "/" come from and where did it go? 
(why didn't it display)

Comment: Where does the "/" come from and where did it go? (why didn't it display)